# How to run a Python Selenium with undetected chrome driver on a Google Cloud virtual machine?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, virtual-machine, undetected-chromedriver

Hi Python and automation enthusiasts,

I have a Python Selenium script that scrapes this [website](https://otv.verwalt-berlin.de/ams/TerminBuchen). The website does not work with Vanilla Selenium and the script is blocked automatically, so I had to use `undetected_chromedriver`.

The script works fine **locally**, but I can't run it on a **Google Cloud virtual machine** because `undetected_chromedriver` needs to run in **non-headless mode**. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I want to leave the script running on the VM 24/7, but I can't figure out how to deploy it and keep it running in a **headless mode** because the `undetectec_chromedriver` always needs to run in non-headless mode.

Here's the simplest version of the script that I want to run.

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

# Set the Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized") # Required for a maximized Viewport
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging', 'enable-automation', 'disable-popup-blocking']) # Disable pop-ups to speed up browsing
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True) # Keeps the Chrome window open after all the Selenium commands/operations are performed 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'}) # Operate Chrome using English as the main language
chrome_options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false') # Disable images
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions') # Disable extensions
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new") # Operate Selenium in headless mode. Does NOT work with undetected_chromebrowser
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Disables the sandbox for all process types that are normally sandboxed. Meant to be used as a browser-level switch for testing purposes only
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') # An additional Selenium setting for headless to work properly, although for newer Selenium versions, it's not needed anymore
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080") # Set the Chrome window size to 1920 x 1080
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtention', False)

# Global inputs
base_url = "https://otv.verwalt-berlin.de/ams/TerminBuchen"

# Instantiate the Chrome driver
driver = uc.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

# Navigate to the website
driver.get(base_url)

# Maximize the window
driver.maximize_window()

# Wait for 5 seconds before closing the driver
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```